# Woocommerce 404 after chang default language

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, htaccess, 404-error

After change default language in Woocommerce from Dutch to English I get 404 errors. I also have installed latest version of WPML. 3 Languages are active: EN - NL - DE. When I edit a link to open an category the link is as follow:

```
myshop.com/en/category/end-user/absorbin/  // result not ok
myshop.com/nl/category/end-user/absorbin/  // result ok
```

this results in a 404 error

when deleting /en/ string for default lang = EN the link works fine.

```
myshop.com/category/end-user/absorbin/ // result ok
```

Is there a possibility to prevent these 404 errors,
instead of changing manually all the links in pages and so on?
Maybe a rewrite rule in .htaccess

But I have no experience with that.

Comment: downvoted as you asked about plugins which is off-topic and in any case without code it is impossible to answer your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the necessary setup in WPML:

[https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/directory-default-language/][1]

Problem solved.